# Possibly stuck in a XY problem with NTP

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have two stand-alone systems, which I'll refer to as Vanguard and Crucible.

Vanguard has an RTC battery, whereas Crucible does not. Vanguard's date and time will be updated periodically by hand. Because Crucible doesn't have an RTC battery, there is a requirement to have Crucible update its time based on what Vanguard's time is, soon after boot. Vanguard and Crucible are part of a LAN with no access to the outside world (i.e. no NTP server pools available). There is zero chance of installing a hardware solution to provide an accurate time source.

My first idea was to set up Vanguard with a NTP server configuration and Crucible with a NTP client configuration.

Crucible's ntp.conf file is mostly unaltered from the default, with the following exceptions:

1. I added the `tinker panic 0 step .001 stepout 1` line to the top of the file
2. Commented out the default pool servers
3. Added `server 192.168.1.80 prefer true minpoll 4 maxpoll 5 burst iburst` at the end of the file

What I've noticed is that after Crucible boots up, it can take a few minutes for it to update its time from Vanguard. Vanguard and Crucible boot times are pretty close, so I don't think it is a matter of one system booting up way ahead of the other.

One thing I tried was disabling the ntpd service and just executing it by hand using `-gq`. Most of the times I execute the software, I get a message that says `ntpd: no servers found`. Eventually, it sets the time. I don't think there's a network connectivity issue because Vanguard and Crucible are constantly talking to each other via TCP without any issue.

The reason why I think this might be an XY problem is because I might be trying to use the wrong tool (NTP) for the job.

Am I using the wrong tool for the job? Is there a better way to solve the issue of updating Crucible's time soon after boot time in a reliable way?

If necessary, I can provide the full `ntp.conf` files for both Vanguard and Crucible.

Comment: First question is how did you manage to find a server without a RTC battery? I haven't seen a system without a CMOS battery in 20 years.

Comment: @doneal24 raspberry pi or pretty much any cheap SBC have no RTC. Not to mention sometimes hardware breaks and even if the motherboard was supposed to have an RTC it may no longer work.

Comment: I don't know if chrony (that you've tagged this question with) does things different, but standard ntp is just for syncing time when the system is running, it should normally be accompanied by a call to `ntpdate` during boot to set the clock.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, ntpdate is deprecated though: https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate there's replacements listed on the page

Comment: I think NTP is the right tool. Exactly designed for what you need.

Comment: The package `fake-hwclock` will help get the clock _approximately_ right while it's waiting to synchronise through NTP

Comment: @ilkkachu there's still no replacement for the wonderfully useful `ntpdate -qu {server}`, sadly. This compares current and remote timestamps, does not attempt to set the clock, does not need root

Comment: @roaima doesn't `ntpcheck` offer very similar operation?

Comment: The question lacks details, like syslog entries, NTP log entries, network topology, etc.